# Having a hard time with generic classes and generic methods in java

Tags: java, generics

New to java, I did search for examples, but I'm having a really hard time.

I have a node class that uses generics:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private int key;
    private T data;
    private Node<T> nextNode;

}
```

The node is Okay.

```
public class GenericDictionary implements GenericDictionary_interface {

    private int capacity;
    private Node<T> [] slots;

    public void add (Node<T> newNode) {

    }
}
```

This is how I would write it, I think. I want the GenericDictionary to work with node objects.

I get an error: "T cannot be resolved as a Type".

Thing is I don't know how it should look like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `GenericDictionary` class would need to be generic as well:

```
public class GenericDictionary<T> ...
{
}
```

At that point, it'll be fine to use `Node<T>` within the class.

If the interface contains the `add` method, the interface should probably be generic too:

```
public class GenericDictionary<T> implements Dictionary<T>
{
}
```

I'd advise against an interface called `GenericDictionary_interface`, by the way... if there's only ever going to be one implementation, you could call the interface `GenericDictionary` and the implementation `GenericDictionaryImpl` - somewhat horrible, but reasonably common. If there are multiple implementations, name the implementation by some differentiating aspect.

Comment: Got me by 19 seconds Jon darn it...jk

Comment: @Kalec if the interface declares an `add(Node<T> node)` method, then it will also need to be declared generically in order to create the "variable" `T`.  On the other hand, if the interface doesn't mention `T` (or some other generic parameter) anywhere then it doesn't need changing.

Comment: @Kalec: Yes, you'd probably want to make the interface generic too. Will edit.

Comment: I kinda knew all of this, but I guess my brain is having an off day, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your second one it doesn't have any idea what type T is so you need to add it to the declaration

```
public class GenericDictionary<T> implements GenericDictionary_interface {

private int capacity;
private Node<T> [] slot;

public void add (Node newNode) {

}
```

}